# Can one open multiple CMD shortcuts that open in different paths?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

Is it possible to have multiple CMD shortcuts, in the desktop for example, that open CMD in a specific directory?

For example, my work directories:

```
W:\PRJ_1\\...
W:\PRJ_2\\...
```

So I would have two shortcuts on my desktop:

```
"PRJ_1" that opens CMD in "W:\PRJ_1>"
"PRJ_2" that opens CMD in "W:\PRJ_2>"
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, therefor a comment. From any window in explorer, you can click the addressbar to type a new path in it. If you type cmd and press enter, it will start cmd in that location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, make sure the shortcut's target is set to something like:

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k pushd W:\PRJ_1`

or

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k cd /D W:\PRJ_1`

The first option, with `pushd` will also work for UNC paths, e.g. `\\servername\path`, in which case a drive letter will be created automatically.

Comment: Good time to mention that W: is a subst disk, is this a problem?

Comment: @FilipeNóbrega That shouldn't matter, if the drive exists, it should work

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out

Answer (score 4):

You may set the "Start in" field of the desktop shortcut:

[image]

Comment: Very simple indeed, thank you